# Status code 500, ReasonPhrase:'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin.forms

I am creating a mobile app using xamarin forms. However, I get the following exception:

> Status code 500, ReasonPhrase:'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent,

While trying to execute `postAsync`. I have no idea where it went wrong.

Here's the code that causes the exception:

```
private async void btnCheckout_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ConstantCS constant = new ConstantCS();
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(constant.URLBaseAddress);
    //Store persive data locally 
    int MyOrdersID_ = int.Parse(Application.Current.Properties["MyOrdersID"].ToString());

    for (int i = 0; i < orderItemList.Count; i++)
    {
        //string postdataJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { UserID = nric.Text.Trim(), Password = pin.Text.Trim() });
        string postJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { orderID = MyOrdersID_, itemID = orderItemList[i].Item_Id, itemName = orderItemList[i].orderItem_Name, orderQty = orderItemList[i].orderItem_Quantity, itemRequest = orderItemList[i].orderItem_SpecialReq, specialRequest = orderItemList[i].orderItem_OtherReq , itemPrice = orderItemList[i].orderItem_IndividualPrice});
        var content = new StringContent(postJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        //HttpResponseMessage orderItemResponse = await client.PostAsync("WebServices/Orders.svc/CreateOrderItems", content);
        HttpResponseMessage orderItemResponse = new HttpResponseMessage();
        orderItemResponse = client.PostAsync("WebServices/Orders.svc/CreateOrderItems", content).Result;

        if (orderItemResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Success", "Order item response = " + orderItemResponse.ToString(), "OK");
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Failed", "Order item response = " + orderItemResponse.ToString(), "OK");
        }

        //var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    string postOrderJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { custID = 1, orderDateTime = now, orderID = MyOrdersID_, orderTotalPrice = totalCost });
    var OrderContent = new StringContent(postOrderJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage orderResponse = await client.PostAsync("WebServices/Orders.svc/CreateOrder", OrderContent);
    if (orderResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Success", "Order Response = " + orderResponse.ToString(), "OK");
    }
    else
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Failed", "Order Response = " + orderResponse.ToString(), "OK");
    }
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MasterDetailPageFood());
    //Display an alert and then go back to the first page
    await DisplayAlert("Thank you for your order", "Your Order will be made shortly", "OK");
}
```

Comment: Seen that it is a HTTP 500 error I don't think the error is in your code. 500 means the error is on the server side. Of course it could mean you're supplying some illegal value which causes this bit that is kind of hard to say.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis thanks I tried hardcoding the values to check if I were supplying illegal values but it still gave me the same error.

Comment: Still, an HTTP 500 error indicates a server-side error. So if that code is also maintained by you I would go look in there first or contact the developer of that code

Comment: @GeraldVersluis thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

The error is on your web service. You should debug your web service and solve the problem there.

Answer (score 0):

That happens when the configuration file of your server is corrupted, `web.cofig` or `app.config`.

I would suggest checking `appSettings`.
Maybe something was changed or deleted.